# Custom hyphenation for words containing accented letters with LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation, accents, russian

*Prenote*: I know, that there are already some questions regarding the hyphenation of words containing accented letters with `LuaTeX`. However, I couldn't find one, that really targets my problem.

Using `LuaLaTeX` and `babel` I would like to correct hyphenation patterns using

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[russian,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{hyphenrules}{russian}
\hyphenation{пус-тын-ник} %normal version
%%\hyphenation{пус-ты´н-ник} %first try
%%\hyphenation{пус-т\'ын-ник} %second try
\end{hyphenrules}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}
\showhyphens{пустынник}
\showhyphens{пуст\'{ы}нник пуст\'ынник пусты´нник}
пуст\'{ы}нник пуст\'ынник пусты´нник
\end{document}
```

I correctly get `пус-тын-ник` for the "normal version". However, I could not figure out any combination to get an accented `ы` and the wanted hyphenation `пус-ты´н-ник`.

While the three alternatives `пуст\'{ы}нник`, `пуст\'ынник` and `пусты´нник` all look the same (at least using my project's font "Newton"), the hyphenation always gives me `пу-сты-́н-ник`, `пу-сты-́н-ник` and `пу-сты´нник` when using the line "first try" or "second try".

How can I get a correct hyphenation?

Comment: you have used U+00B4 (the non-combining acute) you (probably?) want U+0301 (the combing acute), ы́

Comment: David, you are complete right. Another Unicode trap I fell into ;-) Using U+301 (which can be easily added within TeXstudio) fixes that. Now I will have to go through all Cyrillic characters with similar problems. Would you like to make your comments an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used U+00B4 (the non-combining acute) you want instead U+0301 (the combining acute), ы́